# What is keeping the translate arrows from working on the 3D Manipulator Tool

Tags: transforms

I can't figure out why my translate arrows are no longer working. If I use the tool bar or the hot keys I can get the rotate and scale to work as I would expect, but I can not get translate to do anything. It was working in a previous save, so I went back and compared and couldn't figure out any differences. I then proceeded with the old file and it stopped working again. Anyone have any thoughts? I tried changing the system ->selection to OpenGL Select as I found in one forum without luck. I haven't been able to get anything else to work. I've uploaded the file to my google drive if anyone would be kind enough to let me know why this super frustrating thing keeps happening. I'm assuming a setting keeps getting toggle on/off or something similar, but can't figure it out for the life of me.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UNvRaJPZeD5GIx_VaVf7pyUgePMDLXHg/view?usp=sharing

Thank you so much for your help,
Brendan

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Snap to Grid is enabled (and the object is smaller than the grid)

The selection can be moved, you are just not providing an input that would be able to overcome the thereshold of the snap to increments.

If your object would have been 10 time bigger, you would now experiencing a stepping in using the grab tool, but as it's dimensions are small, you are not able to jump over the first step.

The solution would be to disable the "Snap suring transform" option.

[image]

[image]

Comment: That indeed does let me start moving again along the arrow axis. The tutorial I'm using turned that on at the beginning and it is on in both files (the one that works and the one that doesn't). I believe he's using it in the tutorial so we move the vertices the same distance as we follow along. Any reason why having that on wouldn't let me move at all? Actually, now that I'm looking at it the grid in the background is gone which I believe is what we were moving against. Is that why it has stopped working and how would you turn that back on. Thank you very much Carlo for the quick response.

Comment: It's not true that you "can't move"... if you push the mouse up (beyound the screen several times) or add a numerical input, you can see that is working fine. It's just that the grid spacing intersections, which you are snapping to, are way bigger than the moving input vector. Do you agree with this or is there anything else that is not clear/solved?

Comment: I figured out why it was behaving differently. Your comment about the length it needed to move got me looking into the grid. If I take it out of perpective mode and put it into ortho (hitting 5 on the number pad) then the grid comes back and the behavior is working again. Thank you very much for the help Carlo. Wouldn't have gotten there without you. Been pulling my hair out for a couple hours now, and it was so simple...Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Carlo got me on the right track. The issue was that the view had changed to perspective versus ortho. I'm not totally clear on what the difference is, only that the transform requires huge amounts of movement as described by Carlo, rather than being able to move incrementally along a much smaller grid. Thanks Carlo for the help, wouldn't have figured it out without you.

Comment: I think that's beacuse in perspective mode it's forced to use the global grid (0-1) while in ortho you are able to use the grid based on the zoom level, so the steps are smaller and you are noticing that the movement it's not fluid.

Comment: Aw, that would make sense. I've found it super useful in the tutorial to have the grid to help get things aligned, but that's due to the increased granularity available when zooming.